# TypeError while Fine-Tuning DistilBert Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, huggingface-transformers, distilbert, huggingface-trainer

I am trying to fine-tune distilBert model on custom dataset but I am countring the following error while training the model:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

The dataset feature is starbacks reviews and its target variable is ratings from 1-5.

My code:

**Importing Necessaries**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import missingno as msno

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

import tensorflow as tf

from transformers import AutoTokenizer, TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification
from transformers import pipeline
from transformers import DistilBertTokenizerFast
from transformers import TFDistilBertForSequenceClassification, TFTrainer, TFTrainingArguments
```

**Reading the dataset**

```
data_path = '/kaggle/input/starbucks-reviews-dataset/reviews_data.csv'
ds_name = 'Starbucks Reviews'
df = pd.read_csv(data_path)
```

**Removing Null Values**
First I removed all the Users that did not provide reviews
then I replaced all nan values in rating column by using pre-trained model nlptown from huggingface to classify all the reviews with no ratings from 1-5

```
dropped_rev = list(df['Review'][df['Review'] == "No Review Text"].index)
df.drop(dropped_rev, axis=0, inplace=True)

classified_rev = list(df['Review'][df['Rating'].isnull()].values)
model_name = "nlptown/bert-base-multilingual-uncased-sentiment"
model = TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_name, from_pt=True)
toknizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
classifier = pipeline("sentiment-analysis", model=model_name, tokenizer=toknizer)

results = classifier(classified_rev)
labels = []
for result in results:
    print(f"Label: {result['label']}, Score: {result['score']}")
    labels.append(int(result['label'][0]))

if len(labels) == df['Rating'].isnull().sum():
    df.loc[df['Rating'].isnull(), 'Rating'] = labels

df['Rating'] = df['Rating'].astype('int64')
```

**Converting the range from 0-4 to 1-5**

```
df['Rating'].replace({1:0, 2:1, 3:2, 4:3, 5:4}, inplace=True)
```

**Splitting the data into Train and Test datasets**

```
X = list(df['Review'])
y = list(df['Rating'])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,
                                                    y,
                                                    test_size=0.2,
                                                    random_state=123)
```

**Define the toknizer**

```
toknizer = DistilBertTokenizerFast.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-uncased')
train_encoding = toknizer(X_train, truncation=True, padding=True)
test_encoding = toknizer(X_test, truncation=True, padding=True)
```

**Converting Encodings into tensors**

```
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
    (
        dict(train_encoding),
        y_train
    )
)

test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
    (
        dict(test_encoding),
        y_test
    )
)
```

**Define Training Argument**

```
training_args = TFTrainingArguments(
    output_dir='./results',         
    num_train_epochs=2,             
    per_device_train_batch_size=8,  
    per_device_eval_batch_size=16,   
    warmup_steps=500,               
    weight_decay=0.01,            
    logging_dir='./logs',          
    logging_steps=10,
)
```

**Train the model**

```
with training_args.strategy.scope():
    model = TFDistilBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("distilbert-base-uncased", num_labels=5)

trainer = TFTrainer(
    model=model,                         
    args=training_args,                  
    train_dataset=train_dataset,         
    eval_dataset=test_dataset             
)

trainer.train()
```

I am encountring the error on the `trainer.train()` line.

**Here is a lot of things I have tried**

- I have checked the datatype of y_train_encoded and y_test_encoded by typing both are int64.
- I have already checked all the values in the y_train and y_test and all are from 0 to 4
- I have checked the dataset compatability, dataset are compatable the X_train is a list of strings with 650 reviews and y_train_encoded is a numpy array with values between 0-4 and with integer datatype with shape 650 while X_test is a list of strings with 163 reviews and y_test_encoded is a numpy array with values between 0-4 and with integer datatype with shape 163 so I think dataset is compatable
- I checked the X_train and X_test all are strings and there is no mixed datatypes

I don't know yet what is the reason for this error? I want to solve it as soon as possible